KiCAD symbols for JST connectors
I'm trying to add JST connectors library to my KiCAD installation. I'm using KiCAD 8.
I see that Connector_JST is in the KiCAD footprints and the KiCAD 3D shapes but not in the KiCAD symbols.
How come its not there? Is there a work around?

There are hundreds of "generic" connector symbols in KiCAD. Choose one that matches the pin numbers on the footprint and use it in your schematic. Then allocate the footprint to the symbol in the schematic editor.
When, you export to PCB, you can edit the footprint and add the 3D shape.
Of course, if it's a very special connector with complicated (aka non-generic) pin numbers, you can edit the generic part that nearly matches and make a new symbol that you store in a project directory.
